# How to configure my computer to mine when not in use in Windows?

Tags: gpu-mining, windows, mining-setup

I have an older gaming computer with an AMD R7 370 that I would like to mine Monero with when not in use. I am using Wolf's open-source AMD miner. What steps can I take, in Windows 10, to have the computer mine when I am not using it? Can the script automatically start up on boot so that I don't have to manually tell this script to start each time I restart my computer?

Can I set it to mine with either a CLI or in the background (no interface)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's **easy** on a windows machine by adding it as a windows-service and the solution can be tailored for different systems.

Comment: I made a video for setting up Monero as a service, but the same thing can be done for any program. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnWLSy36pQA

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing out ATM but here's how you would go about making one.

Here's what would need to be done for that script/program;

It would need to start on boot (simple)
It would need to detect when you are 100% idle

That being said, it shouldn't be that hard to create.
Using VB or C# you would do something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13384/Getting-the-user-idle-time-with-C)
That may be a problem if you're trying to watch a movie or something on your computer, so you would have to detect if anything is fullscreen or something.
After checking that you are one hundred percent idle, it would open your miner with the correct config and arguments, and every so often checking if you are still idle, and if not terminating the process.

If you can't do this, or need help doing this, contact me, I will be glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use windows Task Scheduler to create a Task, and one of the conditions can be "on idle". https://i.stack.imgur.com/66ycE.jpg

edit: i tried this and it does not work. the task never triggers to start.

Comment: well, I actually tried this and it does not work. no matter how long the computer sits idle, the task never gets triggered to start.

Answer (score -1):

I just created a shortcut to a .bat script and put it in autostart. That's on windows 7 though, but i guess win10 still has autostart functionality :)

Comment: How would this script stop when I started using the computer? I want to still be able to play games.